# Отобразить разные страницы в зависимости от передаваемого параметра в URL

Tags: php

В папке лежат файлы 1.html и 2.html

При переходе посетителя на сайт передается динамический параметр перехода (domen.ru/?subid={dynamic_param})
Нужно чтобы при пустом значении параметра, либо равном {dynamic_param} отображалась страница 1.html, а в остальных случаях 2.html

Заранее благодарен если кто поможет!

Comment: код в студию, тут не телепаты

Comment: if($_GET['subid'] == $dynamic_param || !$_GET['subid']) { // redirect to 1.html
} else { // redirect to 2.html